# Proof verification: Bolzano-Weierstrass (second proof).

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

I construct an other proof of Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem (i.e. that all bounded sequence has a subsequence that converge).

**Do you think that my construction is correct ?**

Let $a:=\inf_{n\geq 1} x_n$ and $b:=\sup_{n\geq 1 }x_n$. If $a=b$, we would have that $x_n=a$ for all $n$ and the claim would be proved. Suppose $a<b$. Let $\mathcal G_0:=[a,b].$ We have that $[a,\frac{b+a}{2}]$ or $[\frac{b+a}{2},b]$ has a number infinite of elements of the sequence. Suppose with out loss of generality that is $[a,\frac{b+a}{2}]$ and set $\mathcal G_1:=[a,\frac{b+a}{2}]$. We define the sequence $(x^1_n)$ that describe all the elements of $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ who are in $\mathcal G_1$. Remark that $\mathcal G_1\subsetneq\mathcal G_0$ and that $\mathcal G_1$ is compact too. Moreover, $[a,\frac{b+3a}{4}]$ or $[\frac{b+3a}{4},\frac{b+a}{2}]$ has a number infinite of elements of the sequence $(x^1_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$. Suppose with out loss of generality that is $[\frac{b+3a}{2},\frac{b+a}{2}]$ and set $\mathcal G_2=[\frac{b+3a}{4},\frac{b+a}{2}]$. We define the sequence $(x_n^2)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ that describe all the elements of $(x_n^1)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $\mathcal G_2$. We remark that, $\mathcal G_2\subsetneq\mathcal G_1$ and that $\mathcal G_2$ is also compact. By continuing this process, we obtain a sequence of compact set $(\mathcal G_k)_{k\in\mathcal N}$ such that $\mathcal G_k$ has an infinite number of elements of $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that $\mathcal G_{k+1}\subsetneq \mathcal G_k$. We define $(x^k_n)$ the sequence that describe the elements of $(x_n)$ in $\mathcal G_k$. By [Cantor intersection theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem), there exist an $x\in\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathcal G_n$.Set $x_{n_k}=x^k_k$ for all $k$. $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is a subsequence of $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ and $$|x_{n_k}-x|<\frac{b-a}{2^k}\underset{k\to\infty }{\longrightarrow} 0,$$
what prove the claim.

Comment: In the same spirit, you can prove that every bounded sequence in $\mathbb R^n$ has a convergent subsequence.  In $\mathbb R^n$, $(x_n)$ is contained in some hypercube. Divide that hypercube into $2^n$ smaller hypercubes, one of them should contain infinitely many points, etc.

Comment: Yes, of course :-)